# Query on Optional fields with QueryDSL

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, option-type, querydsl

I've had some trouble trying to figure out how QueryDSL is working with Java 8 Optional attributes.

I have configured QueryDSL, and queries like `tests?field=value`are working on the String attributes. But as some of the getters of my class have Optional return types, the QTest class that is generated contains `SimplePath<Optional<String>>` instead of a simple `StringPath` for a String attribute. See below :

Test.class

```
@QueryEntity
@Document(collection = "test")
public class Test {

  private String field;

  private String optionalField;

  Test(String field, String optionalField) {
    this.field = field;
    this.optionalField = optionalField;
  }

  public String getField() {
    return field;
  }

  public Optional<String> getOptionalField() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(optionalField);
  }
}
```

Generated QTest.class

```
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QTest extends EntityPathBase<Test> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -609090735L;

    public static final QTest test = new QTest("test");

    public final StringPath field = createString("field");

    public final ComparablePath<java.util.UUID> id = createComparable("id", java.util.UUID.class);

    public final SimplePath<java.util.Optional<String>> optionalField = createSimple("optionalField", java.util.Optional.class);
}
```

The object in the database is such :

```
{
    "field":"value",
    "optionalField":"optionalValue"
}
```

The controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tests")
public class TestController {

  private final TestService testService;

  @Inject
  public TestController (final TestService testService) {
    this.testService = testService;
  }

  @GetMapping()
  public ResponseEntity<Page<Test>> getAllWithPredicate(Pageable pageable,
      @QuerydslPredicate(root = Test.class) Predicate predicate) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(this.testService.getAllTestsWithPredicate(pageable, predicate), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Test> createTest(@RequestBody Test test) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(this.testService.createTest(test), HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

Service :

```
@Service
public class TestService {

  private final TestRepository testRepository;

  @Inject
  public TestService(final TestRepository repo) {
    this.testRepository = repo;
  }

  public Page<Test> getAllTestsWithPredicate(Pageable pageable, Predicate predicate) {
    return this.testRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable);
  }

  public Test createTest(Test test) {
    Test savedTest = testRepository.save(test);
    return savedTest;
  }
}
```

And the repository :

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Test>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QTest> {

  @Override
  default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QTest root) {
    bindings.bind(String.class).first((StringPath path, String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
  }
}
```

So, first of all I wanted to process a containsIgnoreCase on both of my fields. This containsIgnoreCase is perfectly working on the normal field. 
But when it comes to the Optional, with this request : `tests?optionalField=optionalValue` I got this error message :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.SimplePath cannot be cast to com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.StringPath
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslBindings$MultiValueBindingAdapter.bind(QuerydslBindings.java:506) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.invokeBinding(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.getPredicate(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
...
```

That seems to be a normal behavior because of the QTest type generated for this field (`SimplePath<Optional<String>>` instead of `StringPath`), but the fact is that I can't find any working way to deal with this optionalField.

So my questions are :
Can QueryDSL work with `Optional<String>` values ? And if so, how am I supposed to query on these fields ?

Thank you for your help ! :)

Comment: Use BooleanBuilder

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DEBENDRA-DHINDA but I'm sorry I don't get how I should perform that with BooleanBuilder ? Because for me BooleanBuilder is useful when you receive optional parameters within your controller method to perform or/and operations within these parameters. In my case I would like to receive a Predicate because I cannot write controller methods receiving all kinds of combinations of my object attributes. Thank you.